# Adding delimiter to txt file in python 3

Tags: python, twitter

I am struggling to add a delimiter to my output file. I am grabbing data off of twitter in an attempt to export it to a csv for excel. Can someone please look at my code and tell me what I need to alter to get this fixed.

Thanks!

```
for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso): 
    text = tweet['text'] 
    user = tweet['user'] 
    meta = ['created_at']

        vector = [user,text,meta]

        dataToFile = toFileThread(keyWords[0]+'_tweets.txt',vector)
        dataToFile.start()
        entries_added = entries_added + 1
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+'Entries added: ' +str(entries_added))

        current_amount_of_queries = ts.get_statistics()[0]

        if not last_amount_of_queries == current_amount_of_queries:
            last_amount_of_queries = current_amount_of_queries
            time.sleep(sleep_for)
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? We can't help if we don't actually know what is wrong (though check if your indentation is correct here and in your code- SE sometimes gets indentation wonky). I have a sneaky hunch that your problem isn't even in this segment of code, but in the `toFileThread` and starting it (are you really starting a *new* thread to write for every tweet?!? And then never visibly joining them back in? That's a likely problem).

Comment: So its outputting the tweets properly and I am not having an issue with the code. I just need to add a delimiter so its easier to read. I am not sure if I should import csv and add some functionality that way or if there is an easy way to add a delimiter to a .txt file and I can just convert it to a csv there after.

Comment: Well, we can't see the code where you actually write anything to a file; it doesn't happen in this chunk. That's where a delimiter should be added. (and notably, you should probably change that threading behavior. Threads can get weird when they're all trying to access the same thing and you're starting a bunch; plus they'll start taking a lot of resources; It looks like simple file operations would be fine to use here (KISS)).